# Reversing a Vector Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

#### Initial Operation:

Given two unit vectors *u* and *v* in *R^n*, a transformation is applied to obtain a new vector *u_new*, defined as:
$$
u_{new} = u + \langle u, v \rangle v
$$
where *<u,v>* represents the dot product of *u* and *v*, and we can assume for simplicity that both *u* and *v* are unit vectors.

#### Objective:

I wonder how can I find a vector *v_inverse* that when applied in a similar transformation to *u_new* (and then normalized, if needed), returns the original vector *u*. The transformation is  defined by the following equation:

$$
u_{new} + \langle u_{new}, v_{inverse} \rangle v_{inverse} = u 
$$

Is there any way to prove that *v_inverse* always\sometimes\never exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable $v_{\text{inverse}}$ never exists.

Your transformation can be written in terms of matrix multiplication as follows:
$$
u_{\text{new}} = [I + vv^T]u
$$
Reversing this transformation corresponds to computing the inverse of the matrix $A = I + vv^T$. I claim that this inverse has the form $B = I - \frac 12 vv^T$. To see that $B = A^{-1}$, it suffices to show that $AB = I$. To that end,
$$
\begin{align*}
AB &= [I + vv^T][I - \frac 12 vv^T] 
\\ & = I - I\left(\frac 12 vv^T\right) + vv^TI - \frac 12 vv^Tvv^T
\\ & = I - \frac 12 vv^T + vv^T - \frac 12 vv^T = I.
\end{align*}
$$
This matrix of $A^{-1}$ corresponds to the map $u \mapsto u - \frac 12\langle u,v \rangle v$.

For a suitable $w = v_{\text{inverse}}$ to exist, we must have $A^{-1} = I + ww^T$. However, there can be no vector $w$ such that this holds. Indeed, such a $w$ existing would imply that
$$
I + ww^T = I - \frac 12 vv^T \implies\\
ww^T = -\frac 12 vv^T.
$$
One way to show that these are necessarily distinct matrices is note that the left side has a non-negative trace and the right has a negative trace. We have
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(ww^T) = w^Tw = \|w\|^2 \geq 0, \\
\operatorname{Tr}(-\frac 12 vv^T) = - \frac 12 \operatorname{Tr}(vv^T) = - \frac 12 \|v\|^2 = -\frac 12 < 0.
$$

---

It is perhaps noteworthy that if you allow complex vectors and use a bilinear (rather than sesquilinear) "dot-product" over $\Bbb C^n$, then you have the solution
$$
v_{\text{inverse}} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} v,
$$
where $i^2 = -1$.